# How do I sort recylerView items of recent conversation by time?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm basically building a chatting app, the home page shows RecyclerView items of users who are friends. My HomeActivity passes users of the User class to the adapter. The adapter takes each user info and current user info to look up the "chats" firebase database for the last message and last message time to show on the homepage items.

[Homepage Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH8DK.png)

As my User class doesn't have any field "last message time" I cannot compare one user to another for their last message time.

Now how do I compare the recycler view items to bring the latest message to the top?

**User.Java**

```
public class User {
    private String userId, name, username, email, profileImage, token;
}
```

**Message.Java**

```
public class Message {
    private String messageId, message, senderId, imageUrl;
    private long timestamp;
    private int feeling = -1;
}
```

**Firebase database structure**

```
chats - 
      CurrentUserID+ReceiverID
         - lastMsg
         - lastMsgTime
         - messages
             messageId
               - message
               - timestamp
```

**HomeActivity.java**

```
ArrayList<User> users; //declared above onCreate method
users = new ArrayList<>(); //onCreate method

homeAdapter = new HomeAdapter(this, users);
binding.homeRecyclerView.setAdapter(homeAdapter);
    
database.getReference().child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    
                users.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user = snapshot1.getValue(User.class);
                    if(!user.getUserId().equals(mAuth.getUid())){
                        database.getReference().child("users")
                                .child(mAuth.getUid())
                                .child("friendList")
                                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot2 : snapshot.getChildren()){
                                            String check = String.valueOf(snapshot2.getValue());
    
                                            if(check.equals(user.getUserId())){
                                                Log.d("YESCheck", user.getUsername());
                                                users.add(user);
                                            }
    
                                        }
                                        Collections.sort(users, new Comparator<User>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public int compare(User user, User t1) {
                                                return user.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(t1.getName());
                                            }
                                        });
                                        homeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    }
    
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
            }
        });
```

**HomeAdapter.java**

```
public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.HomeViewHolder> {

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<User> users;
    String senderName;
    public HomeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {
        this.context = context;
        this.users = users;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HomeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_home_item, parent, false);
        return new HomeViewHolder(view);
    }



    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HomeViewHolder holder, int position) {

            //HomeViewHolder viewHolder = (HomeViewHolder) holder;

            User user = users.get(position);
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();



            String senderId = mAuth.getUid();

            String senderRoom = senderId + user.getUserId();

            holder.binding.friendName.setText(user.getName());
            Picasso.get().load(user.getProfileImage()).into(holder.binding.friendProfilePic);
            holder.binding.friend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChattingActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("userName", user.getName());
                    intent.putExtra("profilePic", user.getProfileImage());
                    intent.putExtra("userId", user.getUserId());
                    intent.putExtra("token", user.getToken());
                    //intent.putExtra("senderName", senderName);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            database.getReference().child("chats")
                    .child(senderRoom).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.exists()){
                                String lastMsg = snapshot.child("lastMsg").getValue(String.class);
                                long time = snapshot.child("lastMsgTime").getValue(Long.class);
                                @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
                                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

                                holder.binding.friendLastMsg.setText(lastMsg);
                                holder.binding.friendLastMsgTime.setText(dateFormat.format(new Date(time)));

                            }
                            else {
                                holder.binding.friendLastMsg.setText("Tap to chat");
                                holder.binding.friendLastMsgTime.setText("");
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }

                    });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return users.size();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("InnerClassMayBeStatic")
    protected class HomeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ActivityHomeItemBinding binding;
        public HomeViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
            super(view);
            binding = ActivityHomeItemBinding.bind(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For every message add a field "message time" first.

Comment: Either add a new `messageTime` field or reverse the list in the Adapter **if** you know that the list is in an ascending order by default.

Comment: @DarShan 
I added a field messageTime in User.java now it's working but I see duplicate entries of the same user when a new message is sent.
[link](https://ibb.co/qRRtPkq)

**User.java**
`long lastMsgTime;`


**HomeActivity.java**

`Collections.sort(users, new Comparator<User>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(User user, User t1) {
                    return Long.compare(t1.getLastMsgTime(), user.getLastMsgTime()) 
        }
});
homeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
binding.homeRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);`

Comment: @DarShan when I compare by user's name the items doesn't duplicate, whereas when I do compare with lastMessageTime, recent message comes on top but it's duplicating the items.                                                                                                     

`//return user.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(t1.getName());
                                        
    return Long.compare(t1.getLastMsgTime(), user.getLastMsgTime());`
This is how I'm comparing names and time. Is something wrong with the `long` comparison?